# Any way to populate items from xml to Datagridview using c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, gridview

I'm working on the datagridview. In which i have to show the values of the column from the xml to the grid view column.
I have xml like this:-
Also i have a grid view which have two column "ID" and "NAME",I want to populate the values from the xml to grid view .Can anyone help?

```
<employee>
    <empdetails id="1" name="sam"/>
    <empdetails id="2" name="robin"/>
    <empdetails id="3" name="victor"/>
</employee>
```

Comment: Winforms, and not WPF, I presume?  If so, please add the tag.

Comment: Your XML did't come out.  You can edit your message and place the XML between ` and `, or indent it four spaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can read xml to DataSet and pass DataSet `empdetails` table to DataGridView like this:

```
//Create xml reader
XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("fullPathToYourXmlFile.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
//Read xml to dataset
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);
//Pass empdetails table to datagridview datasource
dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["empdetails"];
//Close xml reader
xmlFile.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use XML Linq as below

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(XMl String);
var xmlData = from item in xml.Element("empdetails")                              
                          select new {id = item.Attribute("id") , name= item.Attribute("name")};
dataGrid.DataSource = xmlData.ToList();
```