# how to load a datagridview with my data from xml

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, datatable, dataset

I have this XML:

```
<container_1 attr1="..." attr2="..." attr3="...">
  <rekord_1>
    <type_1 attr1="..." attr2="..." ... />
    <type_2 attr1="..." attr2="..." ... /> 
  </rekord_1>
  <rekord_2>... </rekord_2>
  .
  .
  <rekord_N> ... </rekord_N>
</container_1>
```

I can parse the way I want and show it in a console app (using `XMLElements`, `XMLNodeLists` and a few loops) but I want to make an app with GUI and table view.
My form app could read the XML, but it can only handle 1 tag right now.  For example, if I get the `container_1` tag, it outputs only `container_1`'s attributes by itself, but I want to show the records under the `container_1` in table view also.

I want to make it view-able like my older program in console.

How can I get out the data from my XML so that I will be able to work with the elements/attributes? Because I want to set their place in the table view.
Which documentation should I read? Or is there some example which could be useful to me?

Edited(aug. 20):
Here is the main part of the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream input=null;
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:/";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "xml file | *.xml";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            try
            {
                if ((input = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (input)
                    {
                        XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(input, new XmlReaderSettings());
                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                        dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);
                        DataSet containers = new DataSet();
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[tag];
                        xmlFile.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
```

This function does well the display if my tag is container or rekord and makes this output:
[outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGUqL.jpg)

But I can't display container1+ its rekords,container2+its rekords and so on,only all the containers or all the rekords in same time.

Comment: can you show the code for what you have already tried and what the output looks like?

Comment: I did it.sorry for the late reply,and thanks that you were trying to help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like what you want to do is pull the XML into a Dataset and then feed that DataSet to a Gridview.

and it looks like someone has already asked this question on Stack Exchange as well

[Any way to populate items from xml to Datagridview using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757795/any-way-to-populate-items-from-xml-to-datagridview-using-c-sharp)

**Addition**

what you have is a `DataSet` with multiple `DataTables`. the `DataGridView` is only able to display one `DataTable` at a time.

when you code

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[tag];
```

and put `container_1` in for `tag` you are pulling back the `container_1` **TABLE** of your DataSet.

I am suggesting that you look at the MSDN for [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx), [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx), and [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) to see if this is really going to work for you.

maybe also check this out [C# DataGridView Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial)

it couldn't hurt.

Comment: I found that question too.
In my case if I tell to the program,that tag is container_1 it shows to me all the info about container_1 and its good,but I want to see in same time all the connected record under container_1 tag.And this is my main problem,that I cant do it in same time yet.

Comment: your `container_1`, `container_2` will probably show up in the dataset as separate tables.

Comment: Isnt there any solution to my plan?
I just want a simple table view which display container_1 in one row,after that rekords come in the next few rows,container_2 and so on...Do you have any idea? Thx

Comment: use the DataSet as a memory location, kind of like a variable for all your XML Data.  then YOU will have to decide how you want to pull the information out of the Dataset and into the GridView/Table/whatever you want to use.  if you want `Container_2` after `container_1`  then add another couple lines of code to pull out `container_2`

Comment: I met with that tutorial befor too.I just got time to work on this project again so I'm going to read more.Thanks for your help again!