# Loading Sharepoint Web Services XML List into WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, sharepoint, datagrid

I'm trying to populate my DataGrid with the returned list from a Sharepoint Web Services, all of the tutorials/guides I've found go about doing this with a XAML file.

This is the code I'm using to pull the XML,

```
private String GetListNode()
    {
        webService.Lists siteClient = new webService.Lists();
        System.Net.NetworkCredential passCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        siteClient.Credentials = passCredentials;

        XmlNode getNode = siteClient.GetListItems("Tasks", string.Empty, null, null, string.Empty, null, null);

        return getNode.OuterXml;
    }
```

This returns the pages XML, within this page I'd like to grab these Items,

```
ows_ID, ows_Client, ows_AssignedTo, ows_LinkTitle, ows_Status, ows_Priority, ows_DueDate
```

I'd like to make these items Columns for the DataGrid, then having the data populate. All help will be appreciated, thank you in advanced.

This is not the full XML, this is a small piece,

```
<listitems
xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"
xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<rs:data ItemCount="691">
    <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_ID="2108" ows_Task_x0020_Type="Issue" ows_Client="City University of New York" >
     />
</rs:data>
```

Comment: Can you supply the xml?

Comment: @TomerKlein I have added a part of the XML to my post

Comment: here,
have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757795/any-way-to-populate-items-from-xml-to-datagridview-using-c-sharp

it worked with your xml also!

Comment: @TomerKlein Can you explain how I can use that example in my current situation. That one uses a XML File "fullPathToYourXmlFile.xml", while mine on the other hand is being retrieved from a Web Service.

Comment: you can use it like this:
XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("http://whatever.com/xml...");

Comment: @TomerKlein If you have the time, could you make a response to this thread giving me a sort of mini-guide. I'd appreciate it greatly

Comment: Can you send me the full xml? Then i can test it fully and get back to you...

Comment: @TomerKlein I have provided a portion of the returned XML (There's a Character limit so I can't provide the full thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider the following approach:

```
/// <summary>
/// Bind SP Data Source 
/// </summary>
private void BindSPDataSource()
{
    var data = GetListItems("Tasks");
    var result = XElement.Parse(data.OuterXml);
    XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";
    var taskItems = from r in result.Descendants(z + "row") select new
            {
                TaskName = r.Attribute("ows_LinkTitle").Value,
                DueDate = r.Attribute("ows_DueDate") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_DueDate").Value : string.Empty,
                AssignedTo = r.Attribute("ows_AssignedTo") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_AssignedTo").Value : string.Empty,
            };
    dgTasks.ItemsSource = taskItems; 
}
```

where

```
private XmlNode GetListItems(string listTitle)
{
    var client = new Lists.Lists();
    client.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
    return client.GetListItems(listTitle, string.Empty, null, null, string.Empty, null, null);
}
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid  Name="dgTasks"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Task Name" Binding="{Binding TaskName}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Due Date" Binding="{Binding DueDate}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Assigned To" Binding="{Binding AssignedTo}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I have an exception that says "The type or namespace name 'Lists' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: It is a generated namespace for proxy, you should replace Lists with webService according to your example

Comment: I have a small problem, it seems to be duping the columns Task Name, Due Date and Assigned To? Any ideas as to why?

Comment: In my example the attribute AutoGenerateColumns is set to "False" to avoid columns auto generation

Comment: I have a short question about the same set of code, How would I go about implementing something like string strName = strName.Substring(strName.IndexOf("#") + 1);