# Import XML to datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've been looking everywhere for how to do this but can't find anything that works. I have an application where you have a datagridview and add data using a textbox. i can successfully save the info to a XML file but can't load it:

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// Save
    {
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("NewTable");
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            dt2.Columns.Add(column.Name, column.ValueType);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
            DataRow newRow = dt2.Rows.Add();
            for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                newRow[j] = row.Cells[j].Value;
            }
        }

        dt2.WriteXml(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\_GridData_\test.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Create xml reader
XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("fullPathToYourXmlFile.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
//Read xml to dataset
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);
//Pass empdetails table to datagridview datasource
dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["empdetails"];
//Close xml reader
xmlFile.Close();
xmlFile.Close();
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757795/any-way-to-populate-items-from-xml-to-datagridview-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

```
string filePath =@"c:\data.xml";
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
//Read xml to dataset and pass file path as parameter 
dataSet.ReadXml(filePath );
dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```